# Android animateLayoutChanges does not work properly for ScrollView with fillViewport true

Tags: android, animation, scrollview, show-hide

I am trying to animate layout changes for a `LinearLayout` contained in a `HorizontalScrollView` with `fillViewport=true`. The idea is that I have a dynamic bar of buttons that should distribute to fill the available space, but if there are too many buttons you can start to scroll left/right to see them all.

This all works great, and using `animateLayoutChanges=true` on the `LinearLayout` works smoothly if the `HorizontalScrollView` has `fillViewport=false`, but as soon as it is set to true, jerky motions start to happen:

[image: Jerky motions]

You will notice that the settings button jumps straight to its new position, while the right two buttons initially jump, but then animate a little to their final positions.

For me it seems relatively clear that the problem is that the extra x-offsets introduced by `fillViewport=true` are applied instantaneously, while the remaining shifting of the buttons is animated as normal.

Is there any way to get the animation to consider the effects of `fillViewport=true` as well?

*Details only in case it matters:* My HorizontalScrollView contains a LinearLayout that for each button contains a FrameLayout containing a Button (required in order not to stretch the button clickable area). I have tried applying animateLayoutChanges to the scroll view, to the frames, to the buttons, etc as well, but no combination seemed to make a difference.